# Does xmlParseMemory has limitations on the size of the string passed

Tags: c, xml, xml-parsing, libxml2

I was trying to parse an xml message and get docPtr out of it. 
So I used xmlParseMemory function: `xmlParseMemory(szXMLMsg, iLen)` 
where szXMLMsg is the xml string and iLen is the length of the string.

The function is returning docptr only for the xml message of length upto 3800. Any message of size greater than that(for sizes of 3850 and above) it returns NULL.

Is there a limitation on the size of the xml message we are sending Is there any way I can overcome this problem.

I am using libxml2 library and in the c environment.

Regards,
Kranthi Kumar

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such limitation. I regularly parse much larger chunks of memory. IIn each case I am ensuring the string is zero terminated; the documentation is unclear on the necessity for this. I would suggest your incoming XML is corrupted or perhaps your system has insufficient memory to allocate the XML document.